# with gitlab ci, can I do something like "if tag == 'xx'"?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

with Gitlab CI, I am trying to do something like this:

```
script:
    - do some stuff
    - if tag / branch name == "xx":
        - do additional things
```

is there wa way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab exports many [predefined environmental variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) to the script environment, one of them is `CI_COMMIT_TAG`, which is set when building on tags. With it, assuming the script is interpreted with posix shell, you could normally script it with for example `if [ "${CI_COMMIT_TAG}" == "xx" ]; then something; fi`.